# speed up the query which is taking 2 seconds on 1000000 on active records also on PostgreSQL Sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, performance, activerecord

I'm creating a dynamic query on the server side beside the parameter. However, my query is taking 2 seconds to fetch the records. I'm passing the query through active records let me share the query and Active record rails code

**SELECT (custom_attribute_values.attributable_id) FROM custom_attribute_values WHERE (("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Female') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '12' AND "value_string" = 'Male')) INTERSECT SELECT custom_attribute_values.attributable_id FROM custom_attribute_values WHERE (("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Widowed') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Divorced') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Never married') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Married') OR ("custom_attribute_id" = '17' AND "value_string" = 'Separated'))**

[image]

Here is the time had taken by Postgres SQL

[image]

[image]

```
def fetch_members
 begin
   @filter_result = CustomAttributeValue.find_by_sql(segmentation_query).size
 rescue Exception => e
   render_json_response(response, @success, e.message, e)
 end
end
```

**Above is the Rails code**

Do you know that how can Speedup my query not to mentioned I have tired the indexing but indexing is very cost paying operation in my case

Comment: Could you show us the results from your piece of SQL using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS) in plain text? And your datamodel and indexes. Without this information it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Sure, Let me share the result of SQL query

Comment: I don’t see any results from explain(analyze, buffers) nor any plain text, just images. I also don’t understand why indexing is a problem to you, no index means no performance. You could rewrite your SQL but that’s not going to make a huge difference without some (smart) indexes

Comment: @FrankHeikens Okay, Okay I will explain it more

Comment: You don't have to explain anything, the database has to explain what it is doing: EXPLAIN is a SQL command: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start I would probably try something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.attributable_id FROM custom_attribute_values a
  where custom_attribute_id = '12' 
    and value_string IN ('Female', 'Male')
    and EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM custom_attribute_values b
        where custom_attribute_id = '17' 
          and value_string IN ('Widowed', 'Divorced', 'Never married', 'Married', 'Separated')
          and b.attributable_id = a.attributable_id
    )
```

(there might be some errors I haven't try to execute the query, but it should give you an idea)

But we will need more information as Frank Heikens said in his comment to the question.